# typeerror inst is undefined datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have use datepicker for display the data in textbox in mvc but it give the error

typeerror inst is undefined datepicker

Here is code

```
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#dd").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: don't forget to add jquery and jqueryui reference on your page.

Comment: Can you send me the link

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/download/   and   http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: i have use it but it show error

Comment: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
 

TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js?_=1411979885947 line 2 > eval
Line 3

Answer (score 0):

You should include the jquery libray and datepicker js.

Example code is as follows

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

**[Reference](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**

Comment: as per the error you have mentioned, the jquery datepicker.js may not be included in your page. Please provide the code

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>

Comment: please inspect the page(ctrl+I) and verify that these pages you have included,are really there.

Comment: Check your source code in browser (Ctrl+U) whether all the Scripts you have provided work correctly by click on them.

Comment: @BlankHead Sir i have checked its include all the files

Comment: It give the same error TypeError: inst is undefined

Comment: Hey Manoj. Did you use the same ID which you used for Datepicker anywhere else. ?? Then this problem arises.. Please check that too

Comment: @BlankHead I have check but i do not use same ID, Can you tell me another option for datepeaker in MVC